# ERROR TypeError: _co.Get_products is not a function

Tags: angular7

here , I want to call a function of a component from its HTML template.
but it is showing error as below.
please suggest any changes to solve the error.

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.Get_products is not a function
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MapsComponent.html:49)

MapsComponent.html:49 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 9, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

maps.component.html

```
<button (click)="Get_products()">Function</button>
```

maps.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import {
      AgmCoreModule
    } from '@agm/core';
    //import { google } from 'googlemaps';
    import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    declare const google: any;

    interface Marker {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    label?: string;
    draggable?: boolean;
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-maps',
      templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
    })
    export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {


      constructor() { }
      private products  = []; 
      ngOnInit() { 
    .......
        function Get_products(){
            console.log('Hello');
        }
    ......
          }

    }
```

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `Get_products` outside of `ngOnInit` as a method of the `MapsComponent` class.

```
private products  = []; 

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() { 
    .......
}

Get_products(){
    console.log('Hello');
}
```